# Welcome message Discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

I don't have much experience in `discord.py`, but I'm making a bot. Right now I added the welcoming message:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
     channel=client.get_channel(channel_ID)
     emb=discord.Embed(title="NEW MEMBER",description=f"Thanks {member.name} for joining!")
     await channel.send(embed=emb)
```

but I want to mention the user who joined as this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQdSE.png)

May you help me doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the code to look like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  if member.guild.id !=Guild.id: 
    return 
  channel = client.get_channel(channel_id) # replace id with the welcome channel's id
  await channel.send(f"{member.mention} has arrived!, check out our announcments channel for server and bot announcements!")
  await member.send(f"Thank you for joining {member.guild.name}!")
```

---

This line right here is you only want people that join YOUR server to send a msg, if you don't have any server with your bot in it, will say the msg still

```py
if member.guild.id !=Guild.id: 
    return
```

---

`{member.mention}` is what mentions the user if you are using {} in the sending part you need the f function

---

Next code will make the code call the {}

```py
await channel.send(f"{member.mention}")
```

---

This calls the guild name:

```py
{member.guild.name}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`member.mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.mention)
This returns a string which allows you to mention the member.

```py
@client.event 
async def on_member_join(member):
     channel=client.get_channel(channel_ID)
     emb=discord.Embed(title="NEW MEMBER",description=f"Thanks {member.mention} for joining!")
     await channel.send(embed=emb)
```

You should however keep in mind that because of caching, the mention will most likely look something like this `<@!123456789>`.

Comment: What does it show in the embed then if it doesn't mention?

Comment: As in the pic... basically it has to send a normal message with the mention, then it sends the embed with all the bla bla bla... how I do this?

Comment: @Tomminss What exactly do you want? Edit your question and add it there please.

Comment: See the pic linked in the question

Comment: If I understand you correctly you don't want the mention **in** the embed, but **above** the embed? If so, send the embed via  `await channel.send(content=f"{member.mention}", embed=emb)`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about `client.get_channel`, but you sure can try this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  guild = client.get_guild(serverID)
  channel = guild.get_channel(channelID)
  emb = discord.Embed(title="NEW MEMBER",description=f"Thanks {member.name} for joining!")
  await channel.send(member.mention, embed=emb)
```